# How do I process 3 "input file" fields on one page?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io

I do not want one field with the multiple attribute, I need 3 separate inputs that will be stored in one MYSQL row. When I run the page it only stores the first image in the database and in the file system. I am sure it is to do with the 'tmp_name' but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
Array
(
    [name] => banner_large.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php3936.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 37536
)
Array
(
    [name] => banner_medium.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php3947.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 23017
)
Array
(
    [name] => banner_small.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php3948.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 13887
)
```

---

```
     $ct = 0;
     foreach ($_FILES as $value) {
        $filearray[$ct] = $value;
        $ct++;
     }
     foreach ($filearray as $file) {
        if ($file['error'] != 0) {
           // error: report what PHP says went wrong
           $this -> errors[] = $this -> upload_errors[$file['error']];
           return false;
        } else {
           $this -> temp_path = $file['tmp_name'];
           $this -> type = $file['type'];
           if ($loop == 0) {
              $this -> filename = basename($file['name']);
              $this -> size = $file['size'];
           } elseif ($loop == 1) {
              $this -> filenamem = basename($file['name']);
              $this -> sizem = $file['size'];
           } else {
              $this -> filenames = basename($file['name']);
              $this -> sizes = $file['size'];
           }
           return true;
        }
     }
```

Please help.

Comment: You're not defining `$loop` anywhere? Also this code will not save an image anywhere. Try uploading complete code

Comment: Thank you, $loop was created earlier but I was not incrementing it. Thanks to your help the database now stores all three but still only one file is stored in the file system. I will try again to track it down. The code is too big to upload it all.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning inside the `foreach loop`. Returning **will** exit the loop

```
 $ct = 0;
 foreach ($_FILES as $value) {
    $filearray[$ct] = $value;
    $ct++;
 }
 foreach ($filearray as $file) {
    if ($file['error'] != 0) {
       // error: report what PHP says went wrong
       $this -> errors[] = $this -> upload_errors[$file['error']];
       return false;
    } else {
       $this -> temp_path = $file['tmp_name'];
       $this -> type = $file['type'];
       if ($loop == 0) {
          $this -> filename = basename($file['name']);
          $this -> size = $file['size'];
       } elseif ($loop == 1) {
          $this -> filenamem = basename($file['name']);
          $this -> sizem = $file['size'];
       } else {
          $this -> filenames = basename($file['name']);
          $this -> sizes = $file['size'];
       }
    }
 }
 return true;
```

Comment: that and the for loop should have the $key=>$val construction like `foreach ($filearray as $loop=>$file) {`

Answer (score 0):

2 things I have to mention.

1. Why are you iterating through the $_FILES array and putting it in the exact same state it was in? The arrays by default are numbered from 0, and you just doing the process again. So instead of creating fileArray, just use $_FILES.
2. Why are you setting the image properties to the object properties? The properties are not arrays, so what you can do is either make them arrays (e.g. $this->temp_path[]) or you can insert into database inside the actual foreach loop.

And also your $loop is not defined by the looks of it.

Comment: I tried accessing $_FILES[0] etc. but it gave an error so I stripped the objects out of the array. $loop was defined earlier but if was not incremented (so embarrassing). All works well now.